# conditionally deconstruct object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I want to check an argument, if it was undefined (or false), I will assign a value to it by deconstructing an object

```
function test(x){
  let obj={x:1,y:2}
  if(!x){x}=obj;
}
```

***note:***
I don't want to use a temporary variable

```
if(!x){
  let {temp}=obj;
  x=temp
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: It's not clear from your example what you're trying to achieve. You're creating an object only to deconstruct it again. What's the point? Why not create an object with those variables and you wouldn't have to deconstruct it. What are you returning from the function? The object, `x`? You should really provide your quesiton with more details.

Comment: the function is just simplified, and it is very clear that it accebts an object, but if no argument passed it will use a default one

Comment: Please, provide your real code instead of abstractions. Why should `obj` be defined in function scope? As it was said, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not reassign a value to a variable which is passed as an argument to a function. If it is an object, you can, however, add/modify the properties of that object. But reassigning it will make it lose the reference it was holding from the argument. In your case, if something is undefined, you can not update that reference to hold a value.

For example, in your code -

```js
function test(x){
  let obj={x:1,y:2}
  x = x || obj.x
}
let x = undefined
test(x)
console.log(x)  // x is still undefined
```

What you can do is keep an object and update its properties using a function

```js
function test(a){
  let obj={x:1,y:2}
  a.x = a.x || obj.x
}
let a = {}
test(a)
console.log(a.x)  // a.x equals to 1 now
```

Comment: thank you, I used if(!x) x=obj.x

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean to assign a default value if undefined or false?

```
x = x || {};
```

Comment: No, I mean that I want to deconstruct the default object if no argument passed

Answer (score -1):

Override x value with in the function and return it like this Code below

```
function test(x){
   let obj={x:1,y:2}
   if(!x)x=obj;
   if(x.hasOwnProperty('x')){
   return x.x;
   }
   else{
    return "object does not have property x";
}
}
console.log(test(undefined));    //  {x:1,y:2}
console.log(test(false));    //  {x:1,y:2}
console.log(test(true));    //  true
```

Comment: I want to deconstruct the object, so I get the value of x whitch is inside it

Comment: Here it assign object to the x from the function if x undefined or false ,else it will return initial  value of x is that what you want ?